# Can anyone recommend an IoC container for ASP.NET 2.0 Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, inversion-of-control

As the title says, I'm looking for recommendations for an IoC container to use with an ASP.NET 2.0 Webforms app. I believe that some containers are .NET3.5 or newer only.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) - using the web [extensions](http://www.ninject.org/extensions).

Although it uses 3.5 I think it will work in your 2.0 website.

You'll need 3.5 on the actual machine, but there is just one runtime version executing the app. - .NET Framework v2.0.

This [blog](http://www.joeoncode.com/post/Ninject-2-and-WebForms.aspx), again using 3.5 forms, takes you through steps that should still work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Spring Framework.NET](http://springframework.net/) a lot and been very happy with it, but I haven't used it with ASP.NET. It has a release for .NET 2.0, and even has one for .NET 1.1!

Answer (score 0):

I used StructureMap with 2.0.

I'm not sure if the latest version is still compatible, but the version I used back was just great.